# Get deployed contract from web3

Tags: web3js, testrpc

Using the [Truffle](http://truffleframework.com) console, I'm able to obtain the address of a deployed smart contract by issuing the following:

`MySmartContract.deployed().address;`

In this case, `MySmartContract` is a smart contract written in Solidity and is compiled and migrated with Truffle to TestRPC.

Now, using the [Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js)-library, I'm able to obtain a 'reference' to the deployed smart contract by issuing the following statements:

`web3.eth.contract(MySmartContract.abi).at("0xf6cd8e7179c88aae52339b5268fd67ea2d3305b9")`

...but obviously, I want to treat and access the smart contract like a singleton.

**How do I obtain the address for a deployed (singleton) smart contract without having to specify its address?**

### Update:

While I have seen the term being used in blogs and tutorials, 'singleton' does indeed not cover it exactly; especially considering the fact that, if you upgrade a smart contract, its actually deployed to a different address. (Just trying to verify my understanding of things here; correct me if I'm wrong!)

But how exactly does Truffle know what contract I'm referring to with MySmartContract.deployed()?

Basically, I want to tell `web3`: **"Here is my contract ABI, find me its address on the blockchain!"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For start - there's no way that contract can be a singleton (a single instance in the whole blockchain). Anyone with its source code can deploy it multiple times :)

This means that you need to know the address of the contract that you've deployed (or at least the one that you're going to use).

You could *try* to find the address by scanning the blockchain, however it would require knowing some details (like who created it etc). I'm not sure if it is possible (or enough) to search the blockchain only by contracts compiled data.

Comment: Hi Radmen, thanks for your response! While I have seen the term being used, 'singleton' does indeed not cover it exactly; especially considering the fact that, if you upgrade a smart contract, its actually deployed to a different address. (Just trying to verify my understanding of things here; correct me if I'm wrong!) 

But how exactly does Truffle know what contract I'm referring to with `MySmartContract.deployed()`? Basically, I want to tell `web3`: "Here is my contract ABI, find me its address on the blockchain!"

Comment: You're right about contract upgrades :) Truffle generates quite a lot of boilerplate you can check it in `build` folder. If you want to deploy at your own a contract you need to: 1) compile source code, 2) create contracts interface (using abi data generated by compiler), 3) deploy contracts binary data (it's also generated by compiler) 4) fetch contracts address. Here you can find more details: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Comment: Radmen, thanks for the link. Currently I am able to perform the 4 steps you just mentioned in my front-end application; however, my desired use-case is not to be found. My approach at trying to work with a 'root contract' is misguided, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something - you'd like to be sure that users are interacting with one, selected contract? If so I'm affraid that you need to store somewhere address of deployed contract.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm going for! For now, I'll stick to doing just that. Thanks!

Edit: I must say that I still wonder what the `MySmartContract.deployed()`-function in Truffle does.

Comment: Basically Truffle deploys the contract for you. `deployed()` method simply returns the instance of deployed contract. For simplicity (and mostly for testing) its storing value `address` as, both, static and instance attribute. You should check boilerplate generated by truffle after `build` command :)

Comment: Excellent! I actually already am using the output written to the `build`-folder so that I can easily consume the ABI's in my front-end application but I was unaware of the fact that I can grab the latest address of the contract from there as well! Wonderful stuff, thanks!